# How can I check or prove that a module in angular2 is lazy loaded?

Tags: angular, module, lazy-loading

If I have access to an angular2 application's code and there is a module that is supposedly lazy loaded, is there a way, independent of examining the code, that I can test that module to see if it is lazy loaded. If necessary and there is no other way, I could add code into the module in question to test, if that is a possibility. But what code would I add?

Comment: You can try adding a `console.log('xxx')` to the constructor of the module class and check when it's called (not tried myself yet).

Comment: Clear you network activity before navigating to lazy loaded module and if it is lady loaded, the files needed for that module will be loaded.

Comment: Helpful link about lazy loading modules from Angular https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the ***Network*** tab of chrome dev tools (ctrl + shift + i) in the Google Chrome browser.

If your module is not being lazy loaded you will see a row for the module in the network tab when the site first loads up.

If it is being lazily loaded properly then you will see the row for the module only when you navigate to the corresponding route.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. I haven't been able to test this answer to my satisfaction, but will revisit when I have.

Comment: Could you please provide a screenshot of how that network traffic could be look? Would be great!

Comment: I wanted to check this too. I looked at the Network tab, but in a consolidated Angular 2 development environment, the files are loaded in `bundle.js`. Hence its not possible to distinguish what files are loaded (atleast I think so). I even tried using fiddler but it shows the same `bundled` results. Is there an alternative to OP's question

Answer (score 1):

**Background Concept:**
First of all, one thing needs to be clear about lazy loading. When you lazy load, it basically loads your module lazily in Memory (RAM) not from network or server. Module (js script) already present in Browser cache (HD) - got from network during app loading. Thus by lazily loading particular module helps in memory optimization, not network optimization.

**How to check:** Just put a console.log in constructor function of the module class definition

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { LazyComponent } from './lazy.component';
import { LazyService } from './lazy.service';

@NgModule({
  imports: [ ],
  declarations: [ LazyComponent ],
  providers: [LazyService]
})

export class LazyModule {
  constructor() {
    console.log('Lazily Loaded : LazyModule');
  }
}
```

Comment: console logging a message in constructor doesn't ensure the module is lazy loaded. the constructor is bound to run each time component is initialized.

Comment: i think its a great test! if on startup of your app you see the message from your lazy loaded module in the console, then you know it was not lazily loaded

Answer (score 0):

You can check if your module is being loaded as lazy or non-lazy fashion . Just do Inspect element(right click mouse in browser) or Ctrl+Shift+I , go to network tab and see you are able to see **chunk.js** file in the network calls. if yes , your module is being loaded in lazy manner.